# Given two arrays of hashes, How can we match hashes from both arrays that have a matching key:value

Tags: ruby, hash

In Ruby and given two arrays of hashes. How can we match which hashes from these two arrays both match the same specific key: value of those hashes?

Example

```
A = [{ "Jane Doe" => 10, "Jim Doe" => 6 }, { "Jane Doe" => 11, "Jim Doe" => 12 }, ...]
B = [{ "Jane Doe" => 10, "Jim Doe" => 5 }, { "Jane Doe" => 12, "Jim Doe" => 1 }, ...]
```

Comparing arrays A and B. We would iterate over all hashes in A and B. We are looking for the key "Jane Doe" with the value 10. We see that "Jane Doe" => 10 is the same in both arrays for index 0. we return the whole hash for both arrays as they have different info for the key "Jim Doe".

The result from the script could be the returning of both matches hashes. One from A and one from B. Or if we are iterating first over A and our inner iteration is over B, trying to match to A then we could just return the matched hash from B.

any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Please give an example of what the result would look like.

Comment: all set @Mosaaleb

Comment: Providing how output looks like is lot more easier than vast explanation as to how output look

Comment: I think this is hard for me to answer because there are so many acceptable responses.  I don't want to limit the potential answers with a end result.

Comment: What does the input look like? Do you pass a method these 2 hashes and say "match on `{"Jane Doe" => 10}` (so if both hashes had a `{"Jane Doe" => 11}` you wouldn't care about that), or just "give me things where `"Jane Doe"` matches, or just "give me anything where any key value pair matches? Does order matter? (I.e., the matches are both at index 0 in the example, if `A` had a `{"Jane Doe" => 10}` in the first element and it matched with the last hash in `B`, does that count?

Comment: This also sounds a lot like "write me code, please" where you're not even sure what you want from it (not wanting to limit answers by showing what you want the output to be, which also causes this to border on opinion based, based on each answerer having a different opinion for output, you could end up with a lot of the 'same answer' with the only difference being "here's X's answer but it returns `Y` instead which is "better"). Is this homework? What have you tried? Why didn't it work? How didn't it work?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Note that [so] is not a "write-my-code-for-me" service.

Comment: I'm sorry to get everybody so angry. I wasn't asking anybody to write code for me. I am just asking for help at a time where I was stuck. I thought I was giving a good summary by writing everything out. I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
matched_results = []

a.each do |h1|
  b.each do |h2|
    if (h1.keys & h2.keys).all? {|k| h1[k] == h2[k]}
      matched_results << h1
    end
  end
end
```